# Javascript returns null in Chrome, HTML element in source

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-tag-manager

I am trying to read this HTML in the console in Chrome:

```
<span id="lblSummaryFreight">Kr 79</span>
```

Using this JS:

```
document.getElementById('lblSummaryFreight').innerHTML;
```

However, after the page has loaded, running this line returns null or invalid. If i inspect the element and then run the code, it works as intended and returns "Kr 79". So, is it some kind of DOM issue I am not aware of, or a browser-specific issue?

I am using this as a variable in Google Tag Manager, and it works in 50% of the cases. I don't have access to the source code of the webpage itself, so that's why I need to lean on this rather clunky way of getting the data.

A lot of posts on this suggest that this is because the script is fired before the DOM is ready, but I don't think this is an issue, as I am also testing this in the console after the page has loaded (and the HTML elements are present), and in Google Tag Manager I have specified that the tag should fire after DOM is ready.

Any clues?

Edit / Clarification: I can't alter the code of the page itself, only read the output source, which i am trying with JS via GTM

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but GTM has a selector engine built-in and you can use the DOM type variable to access DOM elements; you don't need to write your own js.

Comment: Thanks Eike, haven't tried that before - didn't solve my issue either unfortunately.

Comment: Where is this span element located on the page... is wrapped in a form element?  How is Kr 79 fulfilled... is it dynamic or static? If it is dynamic caused by a POST I may be able to help

Comment: @Chef_Code: Yes, the whole webpage, meaning everything between the <body> tags, is wrapped in a form element for some reason. It's an .aspx page, and the element I am after is the shipping page on a checkout page, so there are some checks in the background if you change the shipping method for example.

Comment: Same issue here... trying to run a user script... no solution yet...

Answer (score 2):

Don't seem to be able to resolve this issue, and as it seems to be the fault of some quirky source, I will try to figure out another way to get the data I need.

What I have learned:

- The issue seems to be specific to Chrome, as it works in other browsers. This is supported  by the fact that the GTM tag where this code is implemented returns correct values in ~50% of the cases
- Testing the page in Android native browser, it will also return 'undefined'. After reloading the page that fires the tag, it returns correct value.
- The whole DOM seems unavailable in the console. Tried also this:

  document.getElementsByClassName('complete').length

Which returns 0, but there are around 10 instances of the class in the source. After inspecting anywhere on the page, it returns correct number.

- Any delay in running the script won't help, only the symbolic inspecting of elements or reloading the page helps.

So my conclusion is that the way this webpage is built somehow goes against the grain of some browsers - it seems like the source goes out of the memory after the source is loaded. But this is way beyond my level of understanding.

Thanks all for all inputs!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an async issue. Try this:

```
//Using Jquery
$( document ).ready(function() {
    document.getElementById('lblSummaryFreight').innerHTML;
});
```

or

```
//Add this at the end of the body, after all of your content
<script>
(function() {
     document.getElementById('lblSummaryFreight').innerHTML;
})();
</script>
```

Comment: In Chrome, both my original JS and JQuery suggested above fail before inspecting the element. After inspect my JS return "Kr 79", JQuery seems to return the whole source of the page. 

JQuery gives errormessage "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[object HTMLDocument]' is not a valid selector.".

I find it odd that the code works after inspecting, but not before. In my understanding, when I can read the source and see the output in the browser, I should also be able to read it via JavaScript in the console.

Comment: ...which made me think: For some reason, the developers who built this site have wrapped the whole site inside a <form> - that could possibly mess up how the DOM is read?

Comment: Do you need to get access that variable at the beginning? If not you could try using a "setTimeout(function, milliseconds);" and set time to 5 seconds for example and check if it is necessary to inspect page.

Comment: Delays don't work either - only inspecting / reloading. Seems that the DOM is not accessible in the memory for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change how the tag is fired in GTM. Fire them when Window Loaded, and try again.
Maybe the element is being changed in another js file.

Trying jQuery is a good point. I have had similar problems and jQuery have solved them all.

Comment: I will try changing the firing after Window Loaded, but I would assume that if it isn't working in the console, it wouldn't work in GTM either?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But you can try to add another trigger. You say you can acces the information once you have inspected the element, correct? Maybe the element is charged or modified after a hover event or with a TimeOut. Try to create a new trigger on GTM with a delay or even forcing some events (because there must e something loaded when you try to find lblSummaryFreight element).

Comment: Using the console, I have tried running the script after clicking the element, which doesn't work. The only way I have managed to "wake up" the DOM is by inspecting or reloading. Delays don't seem to work either.